# BeanUtils or FieldUtils for dynamic getters and setters

Tags: java, reflection

I want to create dynamic getters and setters for my software as it has dynamic selection values with excel export so it should be performance wise. Data can be in hundreds of thousands so performance should be good enough to run in background instead getting timeout and heap space error. Since every row and column reflection will be used.

Has anyone has done this before ?

Comment: This question is not answerable. Even if we understood precisely what you want to achieve (I don't), all we could answer is "yes, I know someone who has done this before", or "No, I can guarantee that no one has ever done this before". None of these answers would help you anyway. Ask a concrete question.

Comment: And please don't use Indian numbering system. That will just confuse people who live somewhere else.